# Code Igniter - URL Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Hey, i'm trying to get a project to work, but i am having trouble with the rewrite module.
I'm running Wamp over Windows XP. I changed httpd.conf to change the root of localhost to:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project/docroot/"
```

I have htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

my Apache has the rewrite module Activated.
my base_url() in config.php is 'http://localhost/'
in routes.php i have:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";  
$route['our-recipes'] = "recipes";  
and more pairs
```

when i point the browser to http://localhost/ i get the homepage of my site, but when i click on any internal link like to 'our-recipes' it loads but i get the same homepage, with the new url on the location bar. if i try to access 'http://localhost/recipes' i get the same result.

this is my folder structure:
[image: folder_structure]

Can anyone please solve this for me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot (taken from the [wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/))

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```