# CodeIgniter unusual base URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to set the base URL of my CodeIgniter installation to be `localhost/ci/` with the trailing slash as advised in the documentation.

I try this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

And my pagination links are not what I would have expected. Basically,they are broken.

I, however, try this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/';
```

with this set

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

and my pagination links are now good. Is this,

```
$config['base_url']    = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/';
```

the correct way of writing the base URL?

Comment: I think this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660101/code-igniter-url-rewrite

Comment: I don't want to install the rewrite module just yet.I just want to test it out with the index.php being part of the url.

Comment: Without rewrites the second approach is what you want .

Comment: In the question you linked,the op has 'my Apache has the rewrite module Activated.'.

Comment: I meant your second attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember one thing... Your base URL should be like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

And your index URL will be

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Then your site URL will be like

```
"http://localhost/ci/index.php"
```

And if you set the index URL empty like

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

then your site URL will be

```
"http://localhost/ci/"
```

So better at your paginations or anywhere you better use **the site URL**. You can get the site URL like:

```
echo site_url();
```

The site URL will be the combination of the base URL and the index URL:

```
site_url = base_url + index_url;
```